# Better way to exit do-while loop?

Tags: c#, while-loop, do-while

I have a pop for a user to enter a username and then what group to be added to in AD. I can't think of another way to exit my loop other than doing two separate if-statements. Is there a different way to exit the loop other than this? or I am overthinking this?

```
bool isExit = false;
 do
 {
     Console.Write("Enter the username(Type 'exit' to go back to menu): ");
     string username = Console.ReadLine();
     if(username.ToLower() == "exit")
     {
         isExit = true;
     }
     Console.Write("Enter the group name (Type 'exit' to go back to menu): ");
     string groupName = Console.ReadLine();
     
     if(groupName.ToLower() == "exit")
     {
         isExit = true;
     }
}while(!IsExit);
```

Comment: Are you looking for the `break;` keyword?

Comment: "Better" how? Define "better" objectively, or at least measurably...

Comment: `if(username.ToLower() == "exit")` <-- Don't do this (there's at least 3 things wrong with this approach). Instead consider using `if( "exit".Equals( input.Trim(), StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase )`.

Comment: @Dai Wouldn't adding ```Trim()``` ```if(username.ToLower().Trim() == "exit")``` accomplish the same thing? it eliminates the issue of leading space or trailing. Unless you give me more reasons I am not aware of?

Comment: @Maiz Y'ever heard of the Turkish-I Problem? (Not to mention the allocation+copy involved because `String` is immutable in .NET).

Comment: @HereticMonkey by better I meant different approach than 2 if-statements after the console read lines.

Comment: How about "simpler": while (true) { ... if (...) break; }

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately C# doesn't support non-local returns (so I'm envious of Kotlin users), but you can refactor your logic down to a single reusable loop that you can move into its own function - just reserve `null` as a special-value for the quit/exit case:

If you're using a semi-recent version of C#, you can refactor it into a `static`-local function which is handy - but a class-level `static` method is fine too.

```
public static void Main()
{
    static String? Prompt( String msg, Func<String,Boolean> isValid )
    {
        while( true )
        {
            Console.WriteLine( msg );
            String input = Console.ReadLine()?.Trim() ?? String.Empty;
            if( "q".Equals( input, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase ) ) return null;
            else if( isValid( input ) ) return input;
        }
    }

    // 

    String? userName = Prompt( "Enter the username - or enter 'q' to quit", str => !String.IsNullOrWhitespace( str ) );
    if( userName is null ) return;

    String? groupName = Prompt( "Enter the group-name - or enter 'q' to quit", str => !String.IsNullOrWhitespace( str ) );
    if( groupName is null ) return;

    //

    DoStuff( userName, groupName );
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Another way you can try using is a label that essentially works as a break; command but for do-while loops.

```
bool isExit = false;
    do
    {
        Console.Write("Enter the username(Type 'exit' to go back to menu): ");
        string username = Console.ReadLine();
        if (username.ToLower() == "exit") {
            goto exitLoop;
        }
        Console.Write("Enter the group name (Type 'exit' to go back to menu): ");
        string groupName = Console.ReadLine();

        if (groupName.ToLower() == "exit") {
            goto exitLoop;
        }
    } while (!IsExit);
exitLoop:
isExist = true;
//continue rest of your code.
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: What is `isExist`? Did you mean `isExit`? In which case, why bother, since the code is outside the loop at that point? You many want to point out how this code is better than what the user has currently, since it seems to be the same...

Comment: Why use goto?! Use break. What it is designed for.

Answer (score -3):

This is a fine way to do it. You definitely don't want to use the break keyword because that is considered bad practice and I'm guessing this is for school so you would get points taken off for literally breaking your code.

Comment: [citation needed] for "that is considered bad practice". `break;` is part of the syntax of C#. I would complain loudly if I had points taken off for using valid syntax without a reason to back it up...

Comment: Huh? Goto tends to be bad. break is fine thank you.

Comment: Source- classes I've taken and professors that have made it clear that having a forever running loop that can only end when broken is "spaghetti code" unless it's a case statement ofc. "Implement a do-while loop" Seems like the most school-coated question I've ever seen, you can complain about structured programming, clean code, assembly instructions, or whatever, but you're only gonna harm OP.

Comment: @sss: Be aware that "my professor said so" is a valid reason for anything *within their classroom*.  Outside of that, it holds very little weight.

Comment: Having a forever running loop and / if it is a good idea is a completely different thing. My comment concerned your statement about the break keyword.

Comment: Your comment seems the best-intentioned of the lot. I'm not saying there isn't a place to discuss coding practices. I was trying to answer op's question in the best way for school which seemed to be what he was asking it for. Goto is deprecated because we have loops now. It's very inspired by Turing's logical conception of a machine and is the only way to loop in some languages, but I wouldn't use it in a modern language because it does get confusing. As for the break keyword, I don't like it because it makes me feel like I don't have control. It just terminates things without a logical end